# Incomplete netdom computername /add: on 2008 DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller, rename

Have been following a technet article on how to rename Server 2008 DCs following a change of our disaster recovery site.  All went well on the first DC I tried and the new name is showing up.  I ran the following command on the final DC:

```
netdom computername [FQDN Old] /add:[FQDN New]
```

and after an hour it has not completed.  I cannot rerun the command as it say:

```
A remote procedure call is already in progress for this thread.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for the next step?  Luckily as this is a DC at our DR site there are actually no auths to it so rebooting is not too much of a concern (coupled with the fact that the other DC is still functioning after being renamed).  What I dont want to do is reboot it and find I have crippled it somehow.

EDIT:  Have checked the netdom /ENUMerate option and it seems to think everything has completed.  Am attempting a reboot before switching the primary name.  Fingers crossed

EDIT2:  Turns out that it had failed to create teh SRV record.  Re-ran the command after the reboot and it created both records correctly, replicated accordingly and then accepted the change in Primary name.

Comment: Don't rename DCs.  Add new ones.

Comment: Eh, renaming DCs can be done without much issue with a little planning.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: Agreement w/ MDMarra here. I do question, though, why the DR plan requires the DCs to have particular names. That seems to imply hosting other services on DCs that require particular names (since the authentication functionality of DCs is name-agnostic and the DC locator code in clients handles "finding" them). I'd try to eliminate the need for having DCs with particular names to make failover / failback to the DR site more seamless.

Comment: Initially the DCs had been named after the recovery site.  Seeing as we had moved it was thought that a more generic name (BCPDC for example) would be better than the previous site specific site.  There is no requirement for any of the DCs to have a particular name for other services, they only host AD/DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to my original question the next steps I took were as follows:

Killed the netdom process

Ran the following:

```
netdom computername [FQDN] /ENUMerate
```

This told me that the new name had been added.

I then ran:

```
netdom computername [FQDN] /verify
```

This returned that the (A) Record had been created but that the SRV records had not been created.

Trying to run the command again to add the new name failed with the same error:

```
A remote procedure call is already in progress for this thread.
```

I rebooted the DC, ran the initial command again, which completed successfully this time, and then proceeded to follow the rest of the steps to commit the change.  Hope this proves helpful to someone else in the future.

[Here is the link to the Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794951%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)